# Cloth +belt torus

Tags: cloth-simulation

I would like to retighten the clot of my bottle neck with a torus
Can you help me ?
Thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! Are you trying to do an animation that does this? Or you just need an image where the cloth object is "wrapped" and "shrink" by the belt?

Comment: no, I just need an image where the cloth object is "wrapped" and "shrink" by the belt.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use the simulator:

- create the base cylinder (set as collision)
- create the place  (set as Cloth)
- create the torus (set as collision)
- put the objects in this vertical order (from top to bottom): torus > plane > cilynder
- start the animation (set is as long animation)
- during the animation, move the torus vertically, so It can interact with the Cloth
- stop the animation when you are happy with the meshes

(you can do it also animating the torus, in this way you can cache the animation and have a more detail Cloth)

here's a preview of the process:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGlVy.jpg